# Imagemagick Spotify-like duotone overlay

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

Is it possible to achieve this degree of color manipulation using pure imagemagick commands?

[image]

I suppose it might be done with `level-color` and a special transparent png for shapes.
Also is it required to change original colors to b/w before any manipulations with color levels?

Comment: Can you provide the input image before the effect was applied?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way to do it in Imagemagick. Yes, you need mask images. You may or may not want to convert your input to grayscale. But in this case, I suspect you want to start with grayscale.

Here is my input:

[image]

Here I create 4 simple non-overlapping rectangular region binary masks. But in your example it looks like part of the yellow overlaps with the green to make the orange color

```
convert -size 100x299 xc:white -size 300x299 xc:black +append mask1.png
convert -size 100x299 xc:black -size 100x299 xc:white -size 200x299 xc:black +append mask2.png
convert -size 200x299 xc:black -size 100x299 xc:white -size 100x299 xc:black +append mask3.png
convert -size 300x299 xc:black -size 100x299 xc:white +append mask4.png
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then I create 4 different color images the same size as the input and composite them successively with the one each of the masks saving over the in-memory image (mpr:img) that I created from the grayscale image.

**compose method: blend (50%-50%)**
(Note other blend ratios can be applied if desired using -define compose:args=50,50 by changing the two numbers, but keep the total = 100)

```
convert barn.jpg -colorspace gray -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill red -colorize 100 \) mask1.png -compose blend -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill green1 -colorize 100 \) mask2.png -compose blend -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill blue -colorize 100 \) mask3.png -compose blend -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill yellow -colorize 100 \) mask4.png -compose blend -composite \
result1.jpg
```

[image]

**compose method: multiply**

```
convert barn.jpg -colorspace gray -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill red -colorize 100 \) mask1.png -compose multiply -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill green1 -colorize 100 \) mask2.png -compose multiply -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill blue -colorize 100 \) mask3.png -compose multiply -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill yellow -colorize 100 \) mask4.png -compose multiply -composite \
result2.jpg
```

[image]

**compose method: overlay**

```
convert barn.jpg -colorspace gray -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill red -colorize 100 \) mask1.png -compose overlay -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill green1 -colorize 100 \) mask2.png -compose overlay -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill blue -colorize 100 \) mask3.png -compose overlay -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill yellow -colorize 100 \) mask4.png -compose overlay -composite \
result3.jpg
```

[image]

**compose method: colorize**

```
convert barn.jpg -colorspace gray -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill red -colorize 100 \) mask1.png -compose colorize -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill green1 -colorize 100 \) mask2.png -compose colorize -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill blue -colorize 100 \) mask3.png -compose colorize -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill yellow -colorize 100 \) mask4.png -compose colorize -composite \
result4.jpg
```

[image]

There are many other compose methods that you could try. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/

You can also do the same using +level-colors with either black or white as the second color.

```
convert barn.jpg -colorspace gray -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors black,red \) mask1.png -compose colorize -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors black,green1 \) mask2.png -compose colorize -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors black,blue \) mask3.png -compose colorize -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors black,yellow \) mask4.png -compose colorize -composite \
result5.jpg
```

[image]

```
convert barn.jpg -colorspace gray -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors red,white \) mask1.png -compose colorize -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors green1,white \) mask2.png -compose colorize -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors blue,white \) mask3.png -compose colorize -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors yellow,white \) mask4.png -compose colorize -composite \
result6.jpg
```

[image]

You can do it also with -tint.

```
convert barn.jpg -colorspace gray -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill red -tint 100 \) mask1.png -compose colorize -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill green1 -tint 100 \) mask2.png -compose colorize -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill blue -tint 100 \) mask3.png -compose colorize -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill yellow -tint 100 \) mask4.png -compose colorize -composite \
result7.jpg
```

[image]

The results differ with different compose methods. Here are that last 3 with compose over rather than compose colorize:

```
convert barn.jpg -colorspace gray -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors black,red \) mask1.png -compose over -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors black,green1 \) mask2.png -compose over -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors black,blue \) mask3.png -compose over -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors black,yellow \) mask4.png -compose over -composite \
result5b.jpg
```

[image]

```
convert barn.jpg -colorspace gray -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors red,white \) mask1.png -compose over -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors green1,white \) mask2.png -compose over -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors blue,white \) mask3.png -compose over -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img +level-colors yellow,white \) mask4.png -compose over -composite \
result6b.jpg
```

[image]

```
convert barn.jpg -colorspace gray -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill red -tint 100 \) mask1.png -compose over -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill green1 -tint 100 \) mask2.png -compose over -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill blue -tint 100 \) mask3.png -compose over -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img -fill yellow -tint 100 \) mask4.png -compose over -composite \
result7b.jpg
```

[image]

See also https://imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/#duotone for a method using a custom colored look-up table image with the -clut function. Here is that method:

```
convert barn.jpg -colorspace gray -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img \( -size 1x1 xc:black xc:red xc:white +append -size 1x256 gradient: -rotate 90 +swap -interpolate Bicubic -clut \) -interpolate Bicubic -clut \) mask1.png -compose over -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img \( -size 1x1 xc:black xc:green1 xc:white +append -size 1x256 gradient: -rotate 90 +swap -interpolate Bicubic -clut \) -interpolate Bicubic -clut \) mask2.png -compose over -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img \( -size 1x1 xc:black xc:blue xc:white +append -size 1x256 gradient: -rotate 90 +swap -interpolate Bicubic -clut \) -interpolate Bicubic -clut \) mask3.png -compose over -composite -write mpr:img +delete \
mpr:img \( mpr:img \( -size 1x1 xc:black xc:yellow xc:white +append -size 1x256 gradient: -rotate 90 +swap -interpolate Bicubic -clut \) -interpolate Bicubic -clut \) mask4.png -compose over -composite \
result8.jpg
```

[image]

This appears to me to be the closest colorization result to that which was used in your original example.

Comment: Massive! Thanks a lot for clarifications!

Comment: See the last example that I just added using the format duotone method that was in the link shown. It seems to me to be the closest colorization method to what you had in your original example. For a single non-masked image colorization, you may be interested in my tricolorize script at http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/tricolorize/index.php

Comment: First, wow! That's one brilliant set of skills and wits! Thank you so much again for your dedication and willingness to help!